# How to get elements from a text file and searching them in another text file in python 3?

Tags: python-3.x

I have players.txt  It is like:

- Iteration: 1
- Lloris
- 
- Kounde
- 
- Varane
- 
- Upamecano
- 
- Hernandez
- 
- Tchoumeni
- 
- Rabiot
- 
- Dembele
- 
- Griezman
- 
- Mbappe
- 
- Giroud
- 
- Iteration:2
- Martinez
- 
- Molina
- 
- Otamendi
- 
- Romero
- 
- Tagliafico
- 
- Mac Allister
- 
- De Paul
- 
- Fernandez
- 
- Alvarez
- 
- Messi
- 
- Lautaro
- 
- Iteration 3:
- xxxxx
- 
- yyyyy
- 
- zzzzz
- 
- namenamename
- 
- name
- 
- name
- 
- name

And I have superstarplayers.txt like:

- Messi
- Modric
- Ronaldo
- Mbappe
- playername
- playername
- playername
- playername
- It goes like this, a lot of player name

No blank line in superstarplayer.txt
But in players.txt there is a blank line afterward the name of a player line. It is like 1st row is player 2nd row blank 3rd row is player 4th row is blank. One player one blank.

For each iteration, I want to get number of how many players in my iteration. And also I want to get the number of how many players is also exist in superstarplayers.txt
How can I do that in python3. I am learning python file operations.
(in players.txt in every iteration there are not always 11 players the numbers might different)

I'm learning how to read from a txt file, how to write to a txt file. I have no idea about how to get elements from a text file and searching them in another text file in python 3. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you are asking with this

```
def fix_data(lst):
    """ Fixes any blank lines or empty strings"""
    #remove the newline character from the strings if there
    remove_newline = [x.replace("\n","") for x in lst]
    #remove empty strings (your example has them) - also remove whitespace
    remove_empty = [x.strip() for x in remove_newline]
    #return data 
    return remove_empty

#open a text file for reading like this - its wrapped in a fix_data function
with open('/home/lewis/players.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = fix_data(f.readlines())
#open superstar players -  also wrapped 
with open('/home/lewis/superstar.txt', 'r') as f:
    superstar_lines = fix_data(f.readlines())
    

#create a iteration dictionary.
iteration_store = {}
#create a variable to store the iteration no 
iteration = 0
#create a variable to store the iteration start no 
iteration_start = 0
#create a variable to store unknown player no 
unknown_player = 1
#loop each line and and to dict on each iteration
for line in lines:
    #check if an iteration line
    iteration_start += 1
    if "Iteration" in line:
        # get the iteration number from the string by splitting the string on 'Iteration:' and taking the last value, then removing white space
        iteration = line.split("Iteration:")[-1].strip()
        #store this value in the dict as a list
        iteration_store[iteration] = []
        #set to zero 
        iteration_start = 0 
    # after the interation line is found then find the player name in every other space
    elif iteration_start % 2 != 0:
        #check if the player is unknown and rename the line
        if line == "" or line is None:
            #set the line
            line = f"Unknown Player {unknown_player}"
            #increment the player number
            unknown_player += 1 
        #if not an iteration line then store the player name in the dict[list]
        iteration_store[iteration].append(line)
#print the information
print(iteration_store)
#print a new line to seperate the data
print("\n\n")
#loop the newly create dict and print each iteration number and count of players
for k,v in iteration_store.items():
    # check the superstar list for matches
    superstars = [x for x in v if x in superstar_lines]
    #print the information
    print(f"Iteration: {k} - No Players {len(v)} - No Superstars {len(superstars)}")
```

---

EDIT:

Changed the code to take the player name from every other line after the "Iteration" line has been found. This will only work if it follows the following format ALWAYS

- iteration line
- player name (empty or not)
- empty string
- player name (empty or not)

ALSO

If the superstar player is not found, then there must be something that doesnt match like its written `messi` and `Messi` as they are different. The code is sound.

---

Read the codes, research and play with it. Google is your friend.

Comment: hey in players txt it can also be a blank name. But the structure of txt is like
1st row -->player a
2nd row --> blank line
3rd row --> player b
4th row --> blank line
5th row --> no name entry blank name
6th row --> blank line

Comment: Read the comments in the code, I've already added this functionality.

Comment: I dont want to count the superstarplayer.txt I can already do that.
I want to calculate for example in iteration: 1 part in players.txt. Let's say there are 3 players. Those 3 players are also exists in superstarplayer.txt? How many of them exist?

And secondly, I want to calculate how many elements exist in my every iteration. How many players in iteration: 1 , how many in iteration: 2 etc.

Comment: Edited my answer. But I have already counted the amount of players in each iteration. If I have helped you please accept my answer.

Comment: almost dude almost. For iteration 2

Line31: Iteration: 2
Line32: Martinez
Line33:
Line34:Molina
Line35:
Line36:Otamendi
Line37:
Line38:
Line39:
Line40:Romero
Line41:
Line42:Tagliafico
Line43:
Line44:Mac Allister
Line45:
Line46:De Paul
Line47:
Line48:Fernandez
Line49:
Line50:Alvarez
Line51:
Line52:Messi
Line53:
Line54:Lautaro
Line55:

There are 12 players here and 1 superstar in line 52 who is Messi
But the code output says like:
Iteration: 2 - No Players 11 - No Superstars 1
there is no named player in line 38, we should count this too. 
uknow, what I'm saying?

Comment: Edited, but the data format seems odd to me - like why is an unknown player an empty string, but hey.